# ListView filter visual issue

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

When using custom filters on `ArrayAdapter<T>` subclasses, I always end up getting the container `ListView` **showing ALL ELEMENTS for a fraction of a second, at runtime**, before displaying the actual filtered list.

This is especially UX detrimental when the user is filtering with `SearchView`/`TextView`, and the filter event needs to be called `onQueryTextChange`, making the filter appear to reset on every key press.

My implementations usually go like this:

```
public class FilterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListElement> {
    private Context mContext;
    public List<ListElement> listElements;
```

...

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter(){
    return new Filter(){
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            Locale currentLocale = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(currentLocale);

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                //get a COPY of the original elements array not to change it by reference
                results.values = new ArrayList<ListElement>(FilterAdapter.this.listElements);
                results.count = listElements.size();
            }
            else{
                List<ListElement> found = new ArrayList<ListElement>();
                for(ListElement item : FilterAdapter.this.listElements){
                    if(item.filterString().toLowerCase(currentLocale).contains(constraint)){
                        found.add(item);    //no need to create a copy of single element
                    }
                }
                results.values = found;
                results.count = found.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            clear();
            for (ListElement item : (List<ListElement>) results.values) {
                add(item);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

From my understanding, `Filter.performFiltering` subclasses `AsyncTask` (or at least runs in its own thread, never really went to AOSP to check), and `Filter.publishResults` is just a handler for the UI thread for adapter.

Every implementations of Filter I have seen tend to call `ArrayList.clear()` and `ArrayList.notifyDataSetChanged` at beginning and end of publishResults, and I never got filters working without a clear+notify..., although I'm pretty

Any tip for removing that fraction of a second reset and just go from one filtered list to another in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `android:scrollingCache="false"` into the `<ListView>` element in your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I actually stumbled upon a solution 5m after asking, while solving a bad getCount() issue: **problem was synchronization** as initially suspected. I was calling the filter like so...

```
auxAdapter.getFilter().filter(currentUserTextFilter);

//and sequentially I replaced the old adapter on the list
contactsAdapter = auxAdapter;
listViewContacts.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);

//...bunch of other operations in between, and then...
Log.i(activityName, "Item count: " + listViewContacts.getAdapter().getCount());
```

...and `.filter(String constraint)` didn't block and actually took longer than setting the new adapter, so it showed the full list for a bit, and also got me an unexpected (yet correct) item count (when I was actually debugging that count).

Working code uses `filter(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterListener listener)` instead of the constraint only version:

```
auxAdapter.getFilter().filter(currentUserTextFilter, new Filter.FilterListener() {
            public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                contactsAdapter = auxAdapter;

                contactsAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                listViewContacts.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);
                updateTitle();
            }
        });
```